# Iterate over values of a HashMap without creating any new objects to be Garbage Collected

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I am trying to iterate over the values of a HashMap in Java without creating any new objects that would need to be garbage collected.  It is easy to iterate over values using enhanced for loops, like this:

```
for (Value v : myMap.values()) {
    ....
}
```

But this will create an Iterator object behind the scenes (I think?)

The best I have come up with is this code:

```
Object[] values = myMap.values.toArray();
...standard "int i" for loop on the array
```

But to be honest I am not sure what the GC will do with this array.

Is there a perfect way to do this, or is there a way to do this with one reusable object?

EDIT: This is for an Android game, and there a lot of such loops that are creating objects and affecting performance.

EDIT #2: For those who are doubting, my refactoring of just a portion of the most commonly called enhanced for loops, mostly on ArrayLists, has had a significant impact on memory usage based on jvisualvm heap profiling. Of course, part of this is probably because I have too many ArrayLists, or loop through them when it's not really necessary.

Comment: Why don't you want to create an object? I don't think that the overhead of creating an iterator is worth it to create a (possibly quirky) workaround. 
But if there is a good reason, I'm quite interrested to hear it. :)

Comment: And why do you care? Creating an Iterator and garbage-collect it is extremely fast. Don't optimize things that don't need to be optimized.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have no temporary objects?

Comment: Have you seen `fastutil` collections with "fast" iterators?  I discovered these recently.  They are used to iterate map entries efficiently (provide read-only interface, but impl is read/write).  If you have a critical section that requires frequent map entry iteration, it may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this will create an Iterator object behind the scenes (I think?)

Yes it will.

> The best I have come up with is this code:
>
> ```
>   Object[] values = myMap.values.toArray();
>   ...standard "int i" for loop on the array
> ```
>
> But to be honest I am not sure what the GC will do with this array.

In fact this is going to be worse than using an `Iterator` explicitly or implicitly:

- The `toArray()` method allocates a new array and copies the value-set elements into it.
- The call to `values()` *may* instantiate a `Set` object.
- The call to `toArray()` internally calls `iterator()` on the value set object which creates a new `Iterator` instance.

So you are allocating an `Iterator` anyway, AND a temporary array, AND (possibly) a `Set` object.

---

> I profiled the heap and the largest set of objects was `ArrayList$Itr` (not related to this `HashMap` example, but I am currently rewriting all enhanced for loops to standard for loops)

As you point out, that is a different case.  But I still think you are barking up the wrong tree here.  If you are using a recent HotSpot JVM, the cost of allocating and garbage collecting short-lived objects (i.e. ones that don't get tenured) is *pretty small*.  Unless you have a specific reason to reduce the object allocation rate, all of your work may achieve little in terms of actual measurable performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it clears some things up for me.  One thing is that since this is an Android game, it is on the Dalvik VM and not HotSpot.

Comment: I understand that Davlik VM's GC is not be as good as Hotspot's.  But I still would only optimize the use of iterators if your app / game was experiencing GC pauses.

Answer (score 2):

The for-each loop is by far your best option: it is efficient and readable.

Honestly, you will notice no change in trying to avoid creating an iterator. An iterator is specifically made to iterate, so it is efficient and optimized in doing so. Creating an array is  your worst option: it allocates memory for objects that are already in a perfectly iterable data structure.

Concerning your edit: are you sure it is because of the iterator? Did you really micro benchmark it? I am pretty sure there is something else in that loops that takes **much** more time than the simple creation of a very light object. Try to figure out what that is and optimize what really matters before complicating your code.

Comment: I profiled the heap and the largest set of objects was ArrayList$Itr (not related to this HashMap example, but I am currently rewriting all enhanced for loops to standard for loops)